# Understand python threading bug

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Reading http://bugs.python.org/msg160297, I can see a simple script written by Stephen White which demonstrates how python threading bugs up with this exception

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading'
```

Given Stephen White's source code (http://bugs.python.org/file25511/bad-thread.py),

```
import os
import thread
import threading
import time

def t():
    threading.currentThread() # Populate threading._active with a DummyThread
    time.sleep(3)

thread.start_new_thread(t, ())

time.sleep(1)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os._exit(0)

os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

how would we re-write it so that this error is resolved?

Comment: It seems to me you could rewrite it all as `time.sleep(3)`. I think you should specify what the rewritten programs should actually do.

Comment: @JanneKarila The program merely demonstrates a Python bug, which you'll see if you run it in Python 2.7. The request is to work around the bug without upgrading to a Python release that fixes it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[The bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue14308) occurs because of a bad interaction between dummy thread objects created by the `threading` API when one calls `threading.currentThread()` on a foreign thread, and the `threading._after_fork` function, called to clean up resources after a call to `os.fork()`.

To work around the bug without modifying Python's source, monkey-patch `threading._DummyThread` with a no-op implementation of `__stop`:

```
import threading
threading._DummyThread._Thread__stop = lambda x: 42
```

The cause of the bug is best narrowed down in comments by [Richard Oudkerk](http://bugs.python.org/issue14308#msg155887) and [cooyeah](http://bugs.python.org/issue14308#msg158697). What happens is the following:

1. The `threading` module allows `threading.currentThread()` to be called from a thread not created by the `threading` API calls. It then returns a "dummy thread" instance which supports a very limited subset of the `Thread` API, but is still useful for identifying the current thread.
2. `threading._DummyThread` is implemented as a subclass of `Thread`. `Thread` instances normally contain an internal callable (`self.__block`) that keeps reference to an OS-level lock allocated for the instance. Since public `Thread` methods that might end up using `self.__block` are all overridden by `_DummyThread`, `_DummyThread`'s constructor intentionally releases the OS-level lock by deleting `self.__block`.
3. `threading._after_fork` breaks the encapsulation and calls the private `Thread.__stop` method on all registered threads, including the dummy ones, where `__stop` was never meant to be invoked. (They weren't started by Python, so their stopping is not managed by Python either.) As the dummy threads don't know about `__stop`, they inherit it from `Thread`, and that implementation happily accesses the private `__block` attribute that doesn't exist in `_DummyThread` instances. This access finally causes the error.

The bug is fixed in the 2.7 branch by [modifying `Thread.__stop` not to break](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/ab9d6c4907e7) when `__block` is deleted. The 3.x branch, where `__stop` is spelled as `_stop` and therefore protected, fixes it by [overriding `_DummyThread`'s `_stop` to do nothing](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/41c64c700e1e).