# django server ignores POST requests

Tags: python, django, thread-safety, tastypie

This is really strange behaviour. When I issue POST request to many times django suddenly starts to ignore them all. I can see then in firebug but debug server shows nothing. Restarting server doesn't help. Even more, when I try to restart server when this happens I always get:

```
Error: That port is already in use.
```

Restarting the whole machine helps.

I thought it may be related to

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

error I'm having but event after applying workaround:

```
import threading
threading._DummyThread._Thread__stop = lambda x: 42
```

described on [Understand python threading bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193278/understand-python-threading-bug)

I'm still having the same problem.
I don't know ho to diagnose the source of the issue.

Maybe this will be helpful:

```
OS: ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4 
Python 2.7.3
Django 1.4.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've already encountered that, I just delete the terminal then start it again. The cause is long process of the data, the system can't find the right path that's why it's hang

Comment: Just trace your codes, there maybe bugs...

Comment: Is this with development server?

Comment: Yes, it's development server.

Comment: how are you restarting the server?

Comment: @cathy but even if i kill the python process that occupies the port and restart server the problem persists until I reboot the machine...

Comment: @rikAtee - yes I am, it's written in the question.

Comment: HOW. How are you restarting the server?

Comment: @mnowotka don't just kill the python process, close the terminal/prompt you are using because if just kill the process and run it again. The port will still said "The port is already use". And also don't forget to close the browser, they have connection.

Comment: That's what I did every time I encountered that problem and I trace my codes.

Comment: @rikAtee - sorry, I've missed that. I restart django server by pressing ctrl+c and the issueing python manage.py runserver again.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you could use the [`--nothreading`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---nothreading%5d) option to disable the use of threading in the dev server.

```
./manage.py runserver --nothreading
```